# How to Open any file in new browser tab using ASP.NET with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to Open any file from code behind in new browser tab using ASP.NET with C#?

I want to open any file in new tab on a browser using ASP.NET. How can I do this?

I think Navigate.URL can help me, but I don't have idea on how to implement this.

Comment: Share the condition where you need to perform such task. That will be more helpful in giving you accurate answer.

Comment: You can only open a new tab from HTML (anchor tag with `target='_blank'`) or JavaScript (with restrictions imposed by popup blockers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to do something like this:

```
previewlink.NavigateUrl = New Url("someAddres", Url.Absolute)
previewlink.Target = "_blank";
```

Only files supported by the user will open in this new tab/window though.

Comment: Good & nice Answer!, thanks. Helped a lot.